# Why am i getting this error when trying to import pyatogui in Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, libraries

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr

!pip install pytesseract

!pip install pyinstaller

!pip install pyautogui

!pip install pillow

!pip install python3_xlib python-xlib
```

So this is what i have in the first cell.

And then, when i try to import pyautogui, it shows this error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py in get_socket(dname, protocol, host, dno)
    118             try:
--> 119                 s = _get_unix_socket(address)
    120             except socket.error:

10 frames
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DisplayConnectionError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py in get_socket(dname, protocol, host, dno)
    125                     raise
    126     except socket.error as val:
--> 127         raise error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
    128 
    129     # Make sure that the connection isn't inherited in child processes.

DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I guess it has to do with colab being unable to connect to my computer but I don't know.

Comment: Probably cause there is not X server runing. Not sure if it's possible to install a xorg in there. Is it clean to you that the pyautogui would do things in the server windows? If you want to have a notebook and do things to your local windows you'll have to use a jupyter notebook local on your machine.

Comment: so i'd have to use jupyter notebook? is it impossible to use pyautogui in colab?

Comment: Even if it is possible you would control windows over there, the remote machine. What are you trying to achieve with pyautogui?

Comment: i want to take a screenshot of a sudoku

Comment: so this python program solves it

Comment: if the suduku app is running on your machine, you'll have to run this python code in it, your local machine, ether.

Comment: When using colab you are running code in googles machine, if you want the same type of file, to type python code and click run, that runs on your machine, you'll need to run jupyter local. It's not hard to do.

Comment: ok ill try that